# laravel cashier Recive Multiple Webhook for same event(cancel at end of current period) for same subscription Id

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, stripes

Cashier Version: 13.5.3
Laravel Version:8

1. Using laravel cashier we have created a subscription
2. we have canceled subscription using cancelAt method.
3. When we cancel a subscription receive multiple webhook for this
   event (customer.subscription.update).
4. In all webhook requests payload got the same subscription id

We have asked this query also in stripe support. stripe technician said this issue not from the stripe side this issue came from  your side by looking at the 'Source' Stripe/v1 PhpBindings/7.128.0 Laravel Cashier/13.5.3 (https://laravel.com)

Please guide me in laravel cashier what issue occurred so got multiple webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is several reasons that could explain why you are receiving multiple webhooks for the exact same event:

- Make sure that your integration always responds to Stripe events with a 200 status code, otherwise Stripe will retry sending the event https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic
- Also it can happen sometimes and you should make your event processing ​​idempotent https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events

But if you are receiving the exact same event multiple times consistently, then there’s probably an error in your integration using laravel-cashier